# Join 3 tables with 2 where

Tags: mysql, sql, join, average, where-clause

I would like to join three tables with one condition per join (2 conditions) but I am having problems on the second join.

My tables are:

clients

| id | name | surname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Lois | Smitm |
| 2 | Mike | Williams |
| 3 | Jonh | Brown |
| 4 | Dustin | Jones |
| 5 | Robert | Johnson |

transactions

| id | client_id | date | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-12-10 | 350 |
| 2 | 2 | 2022-12-11 | 350 |
| 3 | 3 | 2022-12-12 | 210 |
| 4 | 4 | 2022-12-13 | 200 |
| 5 | 5 | 2022-12-14 | 250 |
| 6 | 1 | 2022-12-15 | 450 |
| 7 | 5 | 2022-12-16 | 850 |

clients_history

| id | client_id | action | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | register | 2022-01-20 |
| 2 | 2 | register | 2022-01-21 |
| 3 | 3 | register | 2022-06-19 |
| 4 | 4 | register | 2022-03-10 |
| 5 | 5 | register | 2022-02-20 |

I would like a query that returns name and surname of those clients that have been registered between January 22 and March 22 (both included) AND the AVERAGE amount of their transactions is between 300 and 500.

I have this code but it is not working:

```
SELECT name, surname
FROM (
    SELECT c.id, name, surname
    FROM clients c
    LEFT JOIN clients_history ch
    ON c.id = ch.client_id
    WHERE ch.action = "register"
    AND ch.date >= '2022-01-01' AND ch.date<= '2022-03-31'
) AS r
LEFT JOIN transactions t
ON r.id = t.client_id
WHERE avg(t.amount) >= '300' AND  avg(t.amount) <= '500'
GROUP BY t.client_id
```

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: LEFT JOIN returns INNER JOIN rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. After a LEFT JOIN a WHERE, INNER JOIN or HAVING that requires a right [sic] table column to be not NULL removes any rows with introduced NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that. PS This is a faq. But one must pin down via a [mre] & write many clear, concise & precise phrasings of one's question/problem/goal to search reasonably. (That issue is not necessary part of your code being wrong.)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CL.CLIENT_ID,C.name,C.surname
FROM CLIENTS_HISTORY AS CL
JOIN CLIENTS AS C ON CL.client_id=C.id
JOIN 
(
  SELECT TR.client_id
  FROM TRANSACTIONS AS TR
  GROUP BY TR.client_id
  HAVING AVG(TR.AMOUNT)BETWEEN 300 AND 500
)X_TR ON C.id=X_TR.client_id
WHERE CL.action='register' AND CL.date>='2022-01-22' AND CL.date<='2022-03-22'
```

To test the query I amended registration data for client_id=1 to '2022-01-27'

Answer (score 1):

```
select c.name, c.surname, avg(t.amount)
from client c
left join transactions t
on c.id = t.client_id
left join client_history ch
on c.id = ch.client_id
where ch.date between "2022-01-01" and "2022-03-31"
and ch.action = "register"
group by c.name, c.surname
having avg(t.amount) between 300 and 500
```